# How to make the call of method that exist in wsdl?

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have wsdl file. 
I used the 'svrutil' to create C# file and add this file to my code. 
Now i don't know how can i make the call of methods in this wsdl.

I don't know how actually i call the method that will make the web service call. 
How do i make this invoke ?

I try to in simple make this call - but i don't see in the sniffer that any network communication is appear ( no http request is made )

Comment: Can you post your code so far please (only the relevant bits)

Comment: this was theoretical question - i don't have a code yet - just want to know how to make the invoke

Comment: You would find the service class instance that can be created from the proxy class generated using svcutil. Just create an instance and the appropriate method you would need to call. You have to make sure that the services url and bindings are configured properly in the client config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file created using 'svcutil' is the proxy class. Make sure that you have provided valid service url to the method call. It will be great if you put some code to communicate your issues to the contributes.

Comment: this was theoretical question - i don't have a code yet - just want to know how to make the invoke.